# How to "hide" an image with javascript after 2 seconds without freezing the page

Tags: javascript, cordova

i'm developing a game in phonegap, i need to hide an image after 2 seconds (with javascript), if the user haven't clicked yet on this image.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you really tried to search this? [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) at MDN. Two seconds from what?

Comment: Set a timer for 2 seconds. Also, add a handler for the click. In the click handler, cancel the timer if it's still active. If the timer fires after 2 seconds, hide the element and cancel the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/8kqhj/1/

Steps followed were :

1. Set a timeout for 2 seconds and add image hiding code in the callback.

   var tid = window.setTimeout(function () {

   ```
    $("#imgToHide").hide();
   ```

   }, 2000);
2. Add click handle for the image and in it cancel the timeout.

   $("#imgToHide").click(function () {

   ```
   window.clearTimeout(tid)
   ```

   });

**See also :**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout

http://api.jquery.com/click/